# How to Reverse All Strings in String Array using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a lot of strings in my string array. I want to reverse it via LINQ. Although I can do it using a for loop using Array.Reverse, I wonder if I can do it using LINQ?

This is my code but its not working as expected:

```
string[] strTemp = new string[] {"Hello", "World", "Foo"};
string[] strResult = strTemp.Select((a, b) => new { Value = a, Index = b })
                   .Select(y => y.Value.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToString()).ToArray();
```

My expected result should be:

```
"olleH", "dlroW", "ooF"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] strResult = strTemp.Select(y => string.Concat(y.Reverse())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to reverse the individual strings in the array, and not reverse the order of the elements, is that correct?
If so, try this.

```
string[] strResult = strTemp.Select(s => Array.Reverse(s.ToCharArray()).ToString()).ToArray();
```

I don't have access to my c# machine, so I can't test this.